# When migrating my sequelize db to mysql in my remote server, the host indicated in config.json changes

Tags: mysql, ip, host, sequelize-cli

I am trying to migrate my sequelize database to my server with mysql.Using sequelize-cli with the command
sequelize db:migrate.
Here is my config.json.

```
{
  "development": {
    "storage":"./db.sqlite",
    "dialect": "sqlite"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "db",
    "host": "",
    "storage":"./db.sqlite",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

The host I put in config.json is changed when migrating from sequelize to mysql.
I don't understand why. I put the ip of my server, it changes it. But when I put any ip it doesn't change it.
Just the ip of my server.
Please help.